# Jinja2 - Create python list containing objects from a prefixed list

Tags: python, jinja2

I use Jinja2 to create a Python class from a template. My template looks like

```
class {{class_name}}({{base_class_name}}):
    
    def __init__(self, {{ parameters|join(', ') }}):
        {{comment}}

        super().__init__()

        {% for param in parameters%}
        self.{{param}} = {{param}}
        {%- endfor %}

        {# First variant #}
        self.parameters1 = {{parameter_list}}

        {# Second variant #}
        self.parameters2 = {{['self.'] | product(parameters) | map('join') | list}}
```

And my python script is defined as

```
from itertools import product
from pathlib import Path

import jinja2

def create_class_from_template():

    templates_path = Path(__file__).parent / 'templates'

    jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(templates_path))

    jinja_env.filters['product'] = product

    parameters = ['param1', 'param2', 'param3']  # For first variant
    parameter_list = [f'self.{param}' for param in parameters]  # For second variant

    template_variables = { 
        'class_name': 'TestClass',
        'base_class_name': 'BaseClass',
        'comment': '"""My generated class"""',
        'parameters': parameters,
        'parameter_list': parameter_list
    }

    template = jinja_env.get_template('class_template.py.jinja2')
    my_class = template.render(template_variables)

    with open('my_new_class.py', 'w') as file:
        file.write(my_class)


create_class_from_template()
```

Which creates the following python file

```
class TestClass(BaseClass):
    
    def __init__(self, param1, param2, param3):
        """My generated class"""

        super().__init__()
        
        self.param1 = param1
        self.param2 = param2
        self.param3 = param3

        self.parameters1 = ['self.param1', 'self.param2', 'self.param3']
        self.parameters2 = ['self.param1', 'self.param2', 'self.param3']
```

But instead of strings the list should contain the members itself, so that it is `self.parameters = [self.param1, self.param2, self.param3]`.

Does anybody have an idea how I could create such a list using Jinja2 and Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can work without changing your script, just make the template like this:

```
class {{class_name}}({{base_class_name}}):

    def __init__(self, {{ parameters|join(', ') }}):
        {{comment}}

        super().__init__()
        {% for param in parameters%}
        self.{{param}} = {{param}}
        {%- endfor %}

        self.parameters = [{% for param in parameters  %}self.{{ param }}{%- if not loop.last %}, {% endif %}{% endfor %}]
```

Slightly neater output as well. And then you only need one template variable (`parameters`), you can do the formatting in the template itself.

```
class TestClass(BaseClass):

    def __init__(self, param1, param2, param3):
        """My generated class"""

        super().__init__()

        self.param1 = param1
        self.param2 = param2
        self.param3 = param3

        self.parameters = [self.param1, self.param2, self.param3]
```

Comment: Both answers solve my problem. I like this answer more, because only one parameter is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for loop in your template which is inside a list:

`[{% for param in parameter_list%} {{param}} {%- endfor %}]`

If you change the code as follow will work

your script

```py
from itertools import product
from pathlib import Path

import jinja2

def create_class_from_template():

    templates_path = '/home/lucas/capagile_codes/templates'

    jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(templates_path))

    jinja_env.filters['product'] = product

    parameters = ['param1', 'param2', 'param3']  
    parameter_list = [f'self.{param},' for param in parameters[:-1]]  # modified line
    parameter_list.append(f'self.{parameters[-1]}') # added line
    template_variables = { 
        'class_name': 'TestClass',
        'base_class_name': 'BaseClass',
        'comment': '"""My generated class"""',
        'parameters': parameters,
        'parameter_list': parameter_list
    }

    template = jinja_env.get_template('class_template.py.jinja2')
    my_class = template.render(template_variables)

    with open('my_new_class.py', 'w') as file:
        file.write(my_class)


create_class_from_template()
```

your jinja template

```
class {{class_name}}({{base_class_name}}):
    
    def __init__(self, {{ parameters|join(', ') }}):
        {{comment}}

        super().__init__()

        {% for param in parameters%}
        self.{{param}} = {{param}}
        {%- endfor %}

        self.parameters = [{% for param in parameter_list%} {{param}} {%- endfor %}]
```

result file

```py
class TestClass(BaseClass):
    
    def __init__(self, param1, param2, param3):
        """My generated class"""

        super().__init__()

        
        self.param1 = param1
        self.param2 = param2
        self.param3 = param3

        self.parameters = [ self.param1, self.param2, self.param3]
```